# How to create substrings from input string using regex?

Tags: regex, substring

How to create substrings from input string using regex?
Each substring should have only 3 contigious characters in the input.

Ex:

```
 input text="1234abc";
```

expected substring

output :`123,234,34a,4ab.abc....`

Comment: you should specify the language/tool you are using..regex implementation differs across languages/tools

Answer (score 1):

Use lookahead

```
 (?=(.{3}))
```

So,first 3 characters would be captured in group within lookahead..Now it would move to the next character (i.e **2** in your example) and again capture 3 characters and so on..

Note:

Group captures within lookaround support is limited to some regex implementations

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following regex:

```
(?=(.{3})).
```

**How it works** - The lookahead looks three characters ahead and puts them into group 1. Then we have a single `.` to eat a character. This moves the regex engine forward so that it can make the next match.

To get the contiguous characters, you need to loop through all the matches and extract the first group. How you do this depends on what language you're using.

You can also visualize this on [debuggex](http://www.debuggex.com/?re=%28?=%28.%7B3%7D%29%29.&str=1234abcasdfasdf). Drag the black triangle along the test string and watch what happens with group 1 in the match.

Comment: you don't need eat any character..`.` at the end is **redundant**

Comment: That depends on the language you're using. In JavaScript, for example, matching the empty string doesn't move the index forward.